# SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006 IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: java, database, wildfly, oracle12c

I have an multithreaded spring application which interacts with database with a set of queries and gives the output. I recently encountered this error and not sure exactly what is its cause. As far as managing the connections on the server, I don't see any issues over there and till now everything was getting executed as expected and I haven't made any recent changes.

I see After some time things started working as expected, but now I'm curios about this error and the cause of it just to prevent this in future.

Posting the log trace as below, any help in decoding this will be highly appreciated.

```
SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2021-03-11 13:46:28,508 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-59) IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
2021-03-11 13:46:28,548 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] (default task-59) IJ030041: Error during closing a statement for: java:jboss/datasources/<pool-name>: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:3247)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1392)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1375)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.close(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:96)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.internalClose(WrappedStatement.java:1491)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.returnConnection(WrappedConnection.java:286)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.close(WrappedConnection.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.closeConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.releaseConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.close(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.close(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:369)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate tries to close a statement but the connection (session) has been closed/terminated for some reason:

> Error during closing a statement for:
> java:jboss/datasources/: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException:
> Closed Connection
>
> SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006 IO Error: A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond

There could be multiple reason why this happen. Maybe it was a network problem that caused a timeout.

You should check with your DBA if he can see any errors on the database server.

Do you have configured database connection validation for your JDBC datasource?
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-to-automatically-reconnect-to-the-database-in-wildfly

Comment: Thank you @SimonMartinelli, I'm in conversation with DB team to get the stats from their side. I haven't been using any validation, however the link you have provided looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

There was a network connection blip between your app server & database server. But what caused it, we can't explain without any more details. If it started working automatically, then it looks like a temporary network issue between the two servers. Or it would have caused if you have used invalid ip/dns name in db server url. But that would require a change from your side to fix the issue.